# How to write $P = \{ [x] \mid x \in S \}$ in first-order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I  am trying to write $P =  \{ [x] \mid x \in S \}$  in first-order logic. My intuition is that it is written like this:

$\forall y (y \in P \Leftrightarrow \exists x (y = [x]) \land  x \in S))$

Is this correct?

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "first-order logic"?  Over what language?  If you mean in the language of set theory, then $[x]$ is not in that language so you'd have to unravel its definition in the language of set theory.

Comment: I see. Well, is it possible to write it not in set-builder notation, but still using [x]? I have all of the other definitions fleshed out (P is a partition of a set S, [x] is the equivalence class of x, with respect to a relation R that I have defined. The only thing I haven't reduced to the language of set theory is ordered pairs.)

Answer (score 1):

$[x]$ is not in first-order-logic. And the definition of equivalence class need a equivalence relation. Let the relation be $R$. Then the correct answer is that $\forall y(y\in P \leftrightarrow \exists x(x\in S\wedge \forall z(z\in y\leftrightarrow Rxz)))$